# How can i remove "index.php" and redirect to home url

Tags: php, html

For example if my home page url is  `"mywebsite.com/index.php"`, I want to access `index.php` on `"mywebsite.com"`

what is the standard procedure that every website uses ?

Comment: Access index.php? You want to "edit" it manually, overwrite with another index.php or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create an `.htaccess` file and write the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

The file must be inside your folder with `index.php`

Comment: assuming they are using Apache or similar. Also, this doesn't need to be in a `.htaccess`; it can be set up in the general config.

Comment: @Jari Okay that what i was looking for. THNX

Comment: @Aayush, you really should mark this as answered if it helped.